# finding MAX value with relational algebra?

Tags: sql, max, algebra, relational

how do i find a max value in a table of numbers with relational algebra?
or how should the relational algebra code be formed?

Answer (score 1):

Lets values = 1,2,3,4,5

the following will yield 5

**project(a)values - project(a1)((select 'a1' < 'a2') ((rename 'a' as 'a1')(values) x (rename 'a' as 'a2')(values)))**